# How to set array element to start of array, and sort the other elements by their score value?

Tags: php, sorting

I have an array with multiple elements, each with a boolean "best_match", and an int "score".

```php
$data = [
   ["score" => 100, "best_match" => false],
   ["score" => 90, "best_match" => true], // <<< should be set as first element 
   ["score" => 60, "best_match" => false],
   ["score" => 40, "best_match" => false], 
   ["score" => 30, "best_match" => false],
];
```

How can I sort this array setting the element with `best_match => true` to the first element, then sort the rest by their score?

Here's what I'm trying with usort:

```php
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
   if ($a->good_match) {
     return 1;
   } else {
     return $b->score - $a->score;
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following sorts as requested, but it also sorts "best_match" matches by score too.

It orders matches by:

1. Best matches from high to low score
2. Not best matches from high to low score.

```php
$matches = [
   ["score" => 100, "best_match" => false],
   ["score" => 90, "best_match" => true],
   ["score" => 60, "best_match" => false],
   ["score" => 40, "best_match" => false], 
   ["score" => 30, "best_match" => false]
];

/** 
    Return score, but add big number to score if it is a best match.
*/
function getScore($match) {
    $bigNumberIfBestMatch = $match['best_match'] ? 1000 : 0;
    return $bigNumberIfBestMatch + $match['score'];
}

usort($matches, function ($a, $b) {
    return getScore($b) - getScore($a);
});
```

*I renamed `$data` to `$matches` since this code sorts matches.

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    if($a["best_match"]){ // Check if the first value is the best match, and return -1, indicating $a is smaller than $b
        return -1;
    }
    else if($b["best_match"]){ // Check if the second value is the best match, and return 1, indicating $b is smaller than $a
        return 1;
    }
    else{ // If both the values are not the best, then sort them based on their score
        return $b["score"]-$a["score"];
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use one return statement comparing the booleans as numerical values and giving an alternate comparison after `??`

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    // Element with true is first else compare based on the difference in score
    return $a->best_match < $b->best_match ?? $b->score - $a->score;
});
```

I would also recommend spaceship operator `<=>` instead of calculating the difference, but both seem to work with your test data.

The data structure you provided didn't match the sort function, so I adjusted the test data:

```
$data = [
    (object) ["score" => 100, "best_match" => false],
    (object) ["score" => 60, "best_match" => true],
    (object) ["score" => 60, "best_match" => false],
    (object) ["score" => 40, "best_match" => false],
    (object) ["score" => 30, "best_match" => false]
];
```

If you have arrays instead of objects then use array access operator.

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) {
    return $a['best_match'] < $b['best_match'] ?? $b['score'] <=> $a['score'];
});
```